# RaisedButton onTap returning null on fresh build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

In my flutter app I have a RaisedButton widget on the first page of my BottomNavigationBar. This page contains a button that should take the user to the fourth and final page of app that also happens to be the fourth page on the BottomNavigationBar (I know this is silly but customer requirements are what they are). This is my RaisedButton:

```
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        color: Constants.secondaryYellow,
                        child: new AlignText(
                          alignmentDirection: Alignment.center,
                          fontSize: 22,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          text: 'Go to Settings',
                          textColour: Constants.primaryWhite,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          navigationBar.onTap(3);
                        },
                        splashColor: Constants.secondaryLightBlue,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                  ),
                )
```

The BottomNavigationBar key is instantiated in the stateful widget just above the build function like so

```
final BottomNavigationBar navigationBar = navBarGlobalKey.currentWidget;
```

If I navigate to a different screen, come back to the home page and then press the button, the button works as intended. However, if the button is the first press I make in the app then the onTap function returns the following error in the console

> The getter 'onTap' was called on null.
> Receiver: null
> Tried calling: onTap

Here is my BottomNavigationBar:

```
BottomNavigationBar(
        key: navBarGlobalKey,
        onTap: onTapped,
        currentIndex: currentIndex,
        fixedColor: Constants.secondaryLightBlue,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.dashboard),
              title: new Text('Page 1'),
              activeIcon: new Icon(
                Icons.dashboard,
                color: Constants.secondaryLightBlue,
              )),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.apps),
              title: new Text('Page 2'),
              activeIcon: new Icon(
                Icons.apps,
                color: Constants.secondaryLightBlue,
              )),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.people),
              title: new Text('Page 3'),
              activeIcon: new Icon(
                Icons.people,
                color: Constants.secondaryLightBlue,
              )),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.question_answer),
              title: new Text('Page 4'),
              activeIcon: new Icon(
                Icons.question_answer,
                color: Constants.secondaryLightBlue,
              )),
        ],
      )
```

The variable navigationBar being called in the onTap is a global variable in main.dart and attached as the key of the BottomNavigationBar

```
GlobalKey navBarGlobalKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'bottomAppBar');

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 40, 55, 1)),
      home: SampleApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: So the error is that your variable `navigationBar` is null. Despite all the code you posted, you have not convinced me why it would not be null. Why would `navigationBar` not be null? Please post that code.

Comment: Post the code, where `navigationBar` is declared and where it is used.

Comment: what is `navigationBar` exactly, is it a class with methods, or a widget ? u should really post the code where it is instantiated.

Comment: Updated the question, it's a global variable declared in main.dart and attached as the key of the BottomNavigationBar